# SQL query many-to-many relationship count specific condition count 0 for those without

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wondering how to query the number of orders for each customer whose status is 'on reorder' and think that I have it pretty close but not quite what I want to accomplish because it is counting just those customers who have 'on reorder' on their status and not all customers (which otherwise should count to 0 where 'on reorder' is not applicable).

I am pretty sure I need to achieve this with a subquery or a join. Any help would be appreciated.  Here is what I have thus far:

```
SELECT custName, ordNum, COUNT(*) AS reorder_count
FROM Orders, Customers
WHERE Orders.custNum = Customers.custNum
AND status = 'on reorder'
GROUP BY orderNum, custName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  It is correct, modern, and more powerful.

You want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.customerName, COUNT(o.orderNumber) AS reorder_count
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
     ON o.customerNumber = c.customerNumber AND o.status = 'on reorder'
GROUP BY c.customerName;
```

Comment: That was very helpful!  I will do what I can to always use an explicit JOIN!